# Error 'CCScene' does not name a type in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I got this error **'CCScene' does not name a type** and **'class SceneManager' has no member named 'createScene'**

My code is below. Can you tell me where I'm wrong? Thanks

**SceneManager.h**

```
class SceneManager : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{
public:
    virtual bool init();  
    static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();
    CCScene* createScene(int sceneID);
};
```

**SceneManager.cpp**

```
CCScene* SceneManager::createScene(int sceneID){
    CCScene* pScene = NULL;

    switch (sceneID){
        case LOGO_SCENE:
        {
            pScene = CCScene::create();
            // LogoScene pScene = new LogoScene();
            break;
        }   
        default: break;
    }

    return pScene;
}

CCScene* SceneManager::scene(){
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();
    return scene;
}

bool SceneManager::init(){
    if (!CCLayer::init())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then, I call to create scene in the **AppDelegate.cpp**

```
...
// create a scene. it's an autorelease object
    SceneManager *pSceneManager = new SceneManager();
    CCScene *pScene = pSceneManager->createScene(LOGO_SCENE);

    // run
    pDirector->runWithScene(pScene);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you forgot using namespace `cocos2d`.

**SceneManager.h**

```
class SceneManager : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{
public:
  virtual bool init();  
  static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();
  cocos2d::CCScene* createScene(int sceneID);
};
```

**SceneManager.cpp, AppDelegate.cpp**

Make sure `using namespace cocos2d;` or `USING_NS_CC;` or prepend `cocos2d::` for cocos2d-x classes.